# Create a new pandas category column on the basis of values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am a doctor looking at surgery data. There is a column in the data frame for admission method.

```
df['ADMIMETH']
```

There are a number of codes for admission method, but the categories essentially are emergency or non-emergency.

Emergency has  17 codes, non-emergency has 3 codes. I want to create a new column with the *categories* emergency, non-emergency by filtering the admission method column. I have used a categorizing method - writing a function to categorize the admission methods into emergency or non-emergency,  and then applied that function to the relevant pandas column.

`emerg = ['2A', '2B', '2C', '2D', '2C', '28', '31', '32', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '2A', '2B', '2C', '2D']`

`nonemerg = ['11', '12', '13']`

```
def filter(x):
    if df['ADMIMETH'].isin(emerg):
        return 'acute'
    if df['ADMIMETH'].isin(nonemerg):
        return 'elective'
```

`df['new_col'] = df['ADMIMETH'].apply(filter)`

```
File ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx:2918, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

Cell In [7], line 2, in filter(x)
      1 def filter(x):
----> 2     if df['ADMIMETH'].isin(emerg):
      3         return 'acute'
      4     if df['ADMIMETH'].isin(nonemerg):

File ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1527, in NDFrame.__nonzero__(self)
   1525 @final
   1526 def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1527     raise ValueError(
   1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1530     )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

as above - value error. I have obviously done soething funadamentally wrong. I would like to keep it as simple as possible as I am a doctor not a developer...

Comment: Change your `df['ADMIMETH'].isin(emerg)` to `x['ADMIMETH'] in `. Or you can consider using `df.mask` or `np.where`.

Comment: If I do that I get , "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: Sorry, use `x in`

Comment: sorry - not sure what you mean

Comment: Change `df['ADMIMETH'].isin(emerg)` to `x in emerg`